# Ruby Rake ActiveRecord Migrate

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to build a simple ruby script that connects to a database and runs some basic queries.

The code is here: https://github.com/mastermindg/rack-activrecord-example

It's not a service - only a script that is run manually to do batch jobs. My problem is that I need to populate the database for testing purposes. I know how to do this in Sinatra and Rails but it's failing as-is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for main:Object
Did you mean?  send
/usr/src/app/app.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/app/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've got the database.yml but I can't tell how to load it since set is failing.

**How do I connect to and query a database using ActiveRecord with basic Rack?**

Answer (score 0):

1) Add this to your `Rakefile` after the `require`s:

```
DatabaseTasks.database_configuration = YAML.load(File.read(File.join(root, 'config/database.yml')))
```

2) Remove `set :database_file, 'config/database.yml'` from your `app.rb` file (I think `set` is a `sinatra/activerecord` method).

Running `rake db:create` may give you an error on your project now,because you're using `json` instead of `JSON` in your `app.rb` file (depending on your local versions), so. . .

3)  Change `puts json Resource.select('id', 'name').all` to `puts JSON Resource.select('id', 'name').all` in your `app.rb` file.

Now `rake db:create` will throw a database error, but that's an error related to your specific database configuration, make an appropriate adjustment to that (this is off-topic from the original question, so I won't address it further) and your app should run as you desire.

---

**More info:**

This [gist shows](https://gist.github.com/drogus/6087979) example contents of a Rakefile that you could use to run Active Record tasks without using Rails or Sinatra.